# finding the most recent date in a filter function using sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, group-by

The following is returned in an array of dates when the 2 conditions are true. I want it to just return the most recent date. I know I can filter a filter, but the logic here is escaping me.

```
=FILTER(data!B:B,data!A:A=A30,data!F:F=B30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(SORT({data!B2:B, data!A2:A}, data!F2:F, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,1)
```

sort data {B & A} based on F in descending order. then sortn all rows (9^9), group them (2), based on A column (2), in ascending order (1). and index only 1st column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would think a Maxifs() would work fine.

```
=MAXIFS(data!B:B,data!A:A,A30,data!F:F,B30)
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing the above Max is doing. I like this logic, but why it is returning 0 for the max between 10/29/2021 and 10/15/2021

Answer (score 0):

If your `FILTER` function is returning an array. You can use the `MAX` function on it to return the highest date:

```
=MAX(FILTER(data!B:B,data!A:A=A30,data!F:F=B30))
```

#### Documentation

- [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en)

Comment: This seems like it should work, but an example is I get 0,   if I don't it returns:
10/29/2021
10/15/2021

Comment: Could you share a sample of your sheet to a better understanding what the problem is?

Comment: Emel  sorry if this was an excel sheet I know how to do that. How do I do that with a google sheet? 
I think my problem might be an import or data type problem and I am not sure where to start to fix this. I'm a teacher. I get a report every day from my students with column A being their name, column b being the data and the rest of the columns being data. The web site with the reports downloads them to an excel file, which I cut and past into sheets. Right now I have over 1100 rows of data and I'm trying to look at each students progress. I think the import is messing up the date some how.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9331167) instructions to do the import from excel to Google Sheets?

Comment: I think I am doing 2.3, but maybe that is my problem. Using Chrome I upload the excel file to my drive, open the excel sheet in sheets, and the copy and paste the data into my data file which was created in sheets.

Comment: You can use the `=ISDATE()` formula to check if the copy paste delete the format of the Dates.

Comment: I did an isdate() on several cells and they all came back true.  That is even more confusing to me, so when I do the (max) on the filter saying or do a maxifs why is it returning 0?

Comment: I think I created a link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fsp7ve08GDfKClVMTgS35SgOR9u3STHewlQUy2ADJr8/edit?usp=sharing     If you looking the results tab, student B A had the same top score on 10/29/2021 and 10/15/2021. When I do a Max on the the filter it returns 0.

Comment: As I see from your Sheet, you are trying to get the dates when certain student do some measure, but you are making the comparative between the mark and the date. `F:F=BX` where `FX` is equal to a mark (ex. `15.05`) and `BX` is equal to a date ( ex. `10/29/2021`). Is this logic correct?

Comment: Yes, and for student BA there are 2 dates and I want the most recent date.  Because there are 2 the filter function alone doesn't work.  If I do a maxifs or add max to the filter function it returns 0 which I don't understand.